# VB.NET CheckboxList doubles when button is clicked. Why?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Every time I click the Delete Button, the check marks double in quantity:

```
Public Class About
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Images\")
    Dim imageArray As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim image As IO.FileInfo

    'clear imageArray


    'list the names of all images in the specified directory
    For Each image In imageArray
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(image.Name)
    Next

End Sub

Protected Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click

    For count As Integer = 0 To CheckBoxList1.Items.Count - 1
        If CheckBoxList1.Items(count).Selected Then
            File.Delete("C:\Images\" & CheckBoxList1.Items(count).ToString)
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

End Class

The checkboxlist isn't refreshed so that the checkbox that I deleted is removed from the checkboxlist. How do I accomplish that? Thanks!

Comment: Solved: Response.Redirect("Delete.aspx")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a button click, Page_Load is ran again, so the code that adds the checkboxes is ran a second time.

Add a check for Page.IsPostBack, and only add the checkboxes if it is not a postback.

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    For Each image In imageArray
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(image.Name)
    Next
End If
```

(I hope syntax is right... Not used to VB)

Comment: Thanks! How to I update the page to remove the checkbox that I deleted?

Comment: @Bruno Add CheckBoxList1.Items.RemoveAt(count) within the If statement

Comment: While my answer works, it would be more correct to follow Davide Piras's answer, because the first part of the code doesn't need to be ran if the checkboxes are not being added.

Answer (score 0):

the whole content of the Page_Load event handler has to be executed only once in your case, so rewrite it like this:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then

    Dim di As New IO.DirectoryInfo("C:\Images\")
    Dim imageArray As IO.FileInfo() = di.GetFiles()
    Dim image As IO.FileInfo

    'clear imageArray


    'list the names of all images in the specified directory
    For Each image In imageArray
        CheckBoxList1.Items.Add(image.Name)
    Next

End If
```